# Check if given safety properties are regular, and if so construct NFAs

Tags: formal-languages, logic, model-checking

Let $\mathit{AP} = \{a, b, c\}$. Consider the following LT properties:

1. Between two neighboring occurrences of $a$, $b$ always holds.
2. Between two neighboring occurrences of $a$, $b$ occurs more often than $c$.

For each of these properties $P_i$ (where $1 \leq i \leq 2$), decide if it is a regular safety property (justify your answers) and if so, define the NFA $A_i$ with $L(A_i) = \mathrm{BadPref}(P_i)$.

Comment: Nice question! Have you attempted to solve it? We expect you to make significant effort before asking a question here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I tried to form the regular languages corresponding to each and then construct an NFA accepting the BaDPref of each regular language. But wasn't able to actually implement it.